# Differential equation - new independent variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Hi I have a question on;

Transform the differential equation:

y∙f’x - x∙f’y =xy∙f

with new independent variables:
u = x^2 + y^2 and v= e^(-(x^2)/2)

I got xy∙(v∙f’v +f)= 0, but the solution is v∙f’v+ f. Why can I ignore xy in front of the parenthese?

Answer (score 1):

If your PDE is

$$
y f_x(x,y)-x f_y(x,y) = x y f(x,y)
$$

making the change of coordinates

$$
\cases{
r= x^2+y^2\\
s = e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}
}
$$

we obtain

$$
\sqrt{\ln s}\sqrt{r+2\ln s}\left(f(r,s)+sf_s(r,s)\right)=0
$$

so we have the possibilities

$$
\cases{
s=1\\
r+2\ln s = 0\\
f(r,s)+sf_s(r,s)=0
}
$$

but

$$
\cases{
s=1\\
r+2\ln s = 0
}\Rightarrow \cases{x=0\\ y=0}
$$

which represents a particular solution.